# Compile failed with runtime scope in Build.gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java web project which is based on gradle as build tool,
I have some jars dependencies which I need them at runtime and when I declare them as `runtime` in the build.grale In eclipse code there are no errors and all code looks nice without errors but when I run `gradlew clean build` in the project I have this:

> Task :compileJava FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

ALSO when I change the scope to `compileOnly` the compilation is working fine, but I need it `runtime` scope!

Is there a solution on how to make the scope `runtime` and the project compile fine ?

Thanks

Comment: What if you use "implementation"?

Comment: Great @gscaparrotti, This is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks so much.
Please add it as an answer and I will mark it.Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `implementation` in order to make the dependency available both at compile time and at run time.